# Is it possible to upgrade the statement that an unramified finite map is a "cover" to the statement that a ??? map is a fiber bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am thinking of the following theorem:

All varieties are projective over algebraically closed fields.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be an unramified finite map to a nonsingular variety $Y$. Then $f$ is locally described as the projection to $Y$ of a subvariety $X \subset Y \times A^1$, where $X$ is defined by an equation $F(T) = 0$ and $D(F) \not = 0$ on $Y$. (D is the discriminant, so this condition amounts to there being $\deg f$ points about each point in $y$.) (Shaferevich Basic Algebraic Geometry I pg. 145)

I think that this is saying that if a finite map to a nonsingular variety appears to be a fibration with dimension zero fibers (i.e. all the fibers are isomorphic, they $\deg f$ reduced points), then it is actually a fiber bundle.

Is there some general condition under which I could conclude that a sufficiently nice map to a smooth variety with isomorphic fibers is automatically a fiber bundle? For example, I could imagine that unramified could be replaced with the kernel of the differential being exactly the tangent space of the fiber. Finiteness was pretty crucial to the argument, so I am not sure what it could be replaced with.

Thanks!

Comment: Locally trivial is not automatic in the Zariski topology, you may consider the etale topology.

Answer (score 3):

[Ehresmann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_lemma) says that any proper surjective submersion between smooth manifolds is a fiber bundle in the smooth category. I think this statement cannot be upgraded to the algebraic category.

Comment: Usually the analogue in algebraic geometry, as far as I know, is the statement that if $f:X\to Y$ is smooth proper then $R^f_\ast \mathcal{F}$ is lisse is $\mathcal{F}$ is lisse (equivalently, higher pushforwards of LCC sheaves are LCC). This is one of the main applications, at least cohomologically, of Ehresmann's theorem. PS, this is known as 'smooth proper base change' in a different light.

Answer (score 1):

Let me supplement the other answers and comments with some more details about what goes wrong for varieties:

1. Even if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is finite and unramified, it is usually not a fibre bundle in the Zariski topology. In fact if $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible and $U \subset Y$ is an open subset, then $f^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is always irreducible; in particular, not a finite number of copies of $U$.
2. (Not quite what you asked for, but relevant to @Qiaochu Yuan's answer.) A smooth morphism between smooth varieties need not even have isomorphic fibres, unlike the case of manifolds: for example one can quite easily write down a morphism where all the fibres are elliptic curves but the $j$-invariant is varying.